# How does one overload / redefine binary operators in Julia?

Tags: operator-overloading, overloading, julia, binary-operators, or-operator

I keep losing my reference on how to redefine say the `||`  ("or")  or `&&` ("and") binary operators.  I read somewhere that one has to first do `importall Base` . Then I tried

```
Base.||( x::MyType, y::MyType ) = dosomething( x, y )
```

and also

```
Base.or( x::MyType, y::MyType ) = dosomething( x, y )
```

But none of these worked. I would appreciate if somebody could give a reference explaining the basics of how to do this... I was unable to find one with queries such as "redefine binary operator in Julia"...

Answer (score 5):

As && and || are short circuit operations, they can't be overloaded, without adding a special construction separate from functions. To call a function, you need to evaluate all the arguments, and that would not be a short circuit evaluation.

You might be able to overload & and | instead, but it is hard to tell without an example use case.

Comment: I understand. That makes sense. I would be fine with overloading `|`  instead. My use case similar to having '|' do a set union for the case of sets. Seems that operator got deprecated (wonder why?). So in any case, it seems that the syntax  `Base.|( x, y ) = compute_bitwise_or(x,y)` does work for non-short circuit operators. Would it be possible to be more specific about the error given by trying to define `Base.||`, mentioning the special short-circuiting character of `||`, for instance? Should I open an issue for this?